# How to open a view(another xib) on clicking of a uiimage in ipad application

Tags: ios, ipad

How to open a view(another xib) on clicking of a uiimage in ipad application .Please tell me if anyone knows thanks in advance.
i read somewhere that it can be done by using custom delegates of class ,but i not able to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you have to make the user interaction for imageView in xib enable as shown in illustration see [image]

now add one tapgastureREcognizer as below

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
                tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
                [fr addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

here `fr` is the imageview and the `tapAction:` is method where you can show the other view (xib)

Comment: if this is the answer you are looking for and if it is perfect one just accept the answer by clicking on the right mark under the down vote button Please

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I have done this in the past.

A) create a UIButon and set the image as its background.

B) You can create touch gesture recogniser. Upon touch you can get the coordinates of where the user touched and check to see if it was in fact on the image.

The you just display your other view.